# Can't Create a JBoss Server in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss

I'm using eclipse indigo and I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](http://www.software-architect.net/tutorials/setting-up-a-web-development-environment-with-eclipse/setting-up-the-application-server-jboss.html) to set up jBoss. It says...

> When installing software from this site, some different categories are shown to install - I have chosen the first one which is “Abridged JBoss tools 3.3”

which I have installed. Then, it says:

> The next step after the plugins have been installed is again to install the application server itself.

Which I have (jBoss 4.2.2.GA). So now I'm supposed to do this:

> Now, define the server runtime in Eclipse. Open "Window => Preferences" and navigate to the "Server => Runtime Environments" node. Press the "Add" button and in the "New Server Environment" dialog, choose "JBoss Community => JBoss 7.1 runtime". Press the "Next >" button. In the next dialog, enter the path to the directory where you have unpacked the JBoss server earlier.

And I'd love to do that, but I don't see the jBoss Runtime Option. I only see "Basic" and then HTTP Preview and HTTP Server (also J2EE Runtime). Plus, I don't have a JBoss perspective, which I should have, and JBoss Central didn't show up when I restarted eclipse. I tried searching my jBoss folder for runtime environments...I got nothing. It's like I don't have the JBoss Tools.

Apparently, this tutorial is exactly what I need to do to set up my server (says my co-worker). But I'm failing and I'm not sure why. I did set-up a JBoss server once before on a different (and also, now broken) laptop with no problem, but now I'm having trouble since nothing seems to be working correctly. Does anyone else know why this is failing/what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In eclipse, after clicking on "ADD" you can "download additionnal server adapters" on the top right of your frame! try to click on this and select "JBOSS" if it was not present!

By default i had Jboss in the list...

hope this helps!